# The relation between data bandwidth (BW) and BW of the local oscillator of a transmitter

Tags: transmitter, pll, digital-modulation

Say we have some sort of data we want to send by means of a transmitter having a local oscillator as its carrier. The local oscillator can simply be realized by a phase locked loop with a certain loop bandwidth, lets call it BW_LO. The data we are going to send has bandwidth called BW_D. The data are modulated by FM or whatever you think is more appropriate. The question is the following:

Do we have to keep BW_D less than BW_LO for proper data transmission? It seems so to me but I do not understand why?

Comment: Why the complication; the oscillator is just an oscillator. What you need to concentrate on is the modulation method and it's BW.

Answer (score 1):

Many systems generally keep the data bandwidth *much* less than the LO bandwidth, at least for common *narrowband* systems such as individual WiFi and LTE channels. A lot of components in the actual radio receiver chain, especially the LNA and certain filters, are much easier to implement for narrowband signals since you can take advantage of narrowband constructs such as resonant tanks and LC filters.

This is also important for regulatory and spectrum sharing reasons, since narrowband signals require less space on the already congested spectrum that all radio users must share.

There are wideband and even ultrawideband systems out there, which have their own design tradeoffs. They still keep the data bandwidth low enough that they do not reach all the way down to DC, since antennas and single conductor waveguides cannot operate all the way down to DC; when they overlap with other frequencies they use channel spreading techniques to spread their power to avoid interfering with any particular users of the bands they overlap.

There's also a frequency overlap issue if you try to make the data bandwidth too large: if your local oscillator is operating at 1 GHz and your I/Q baseband signal covers -1.1 GHz to 1.1 GHz, then the baseband components at -0.95 GHz and -1.05 GHz are both indistinguishable as they end up at 0.05 GHz at the (purely real) output of the mixer.